# Pegar um elemento de uma lista e pesquisar em outra lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu estou tendo um problema relacionado a listas, tenho alguns arquivos para acessar e passá-los para listas (3 arquivos para 3 listas).

Basicamente um dos arquivos teria dados de técnicos do IBGE, e preciso pegar esse número de matrícula dele e procurar em outra lista essa string para validar se o técnico realmente existe, é preciso fazer o mesmo para outra lista que detém as cidades onde foram feitos os cadastros.

Eu cheguei a dar uma olhada relacionado a pesquisar em lista com > `index`
porém pelo que entendi ela procura pelo primeiro elemento repetido e mostra a sua posição;

Também olhei o  `if` elemento in lista, no entanto o que eu desejo é pegar a matrícula do técnico (um arquivo) e a cidade (outro arquivo) e pesquisar na pesquisa do IBGE (o terceiro arquivo) se aquele técnico e a cidade existe, sendo assim eu validaria e com isso iria criar umas estatísticas de acordo com a resposta do pessoal que respondeu a pesquisa.

Até agora fiz um código simples com o que aprendi até o momento, eu consigo acessar os arquivos, consigo dar um `split` , pra melhorar a visualização, sei *`printar`* os elementos da lista (da forma como fiz os elementos estão separados em cada linha, mas seria preferível separá-los em partes menores.

Exemplo de como tá agora:

```
 'T010;4404;08430-026;6;64;6;4;2;-;4;6;2;-;2;1;1;7;1992;4;1;1\n', 'T011;866;04854-280;1;62;6;1;2;-;10;5;3;-;6;1;2;4;1970;5;2;3\n', 
A melhor forma seria algo tipo 'T010;','4404;','08430-026;','6;','64;','6;','4;','2;','-;','4;','6;','2;'...\n',
```

),

No caso eu pegaria essa '`4404`' que seria pesquisado em um arquivo de regiões, isso me devolveria a cidade caso existisse esse 4404, pegaria a cidade relacionada a esse número e em conjunto com a matrícula do técnico: 'T010' pesquisaria no arquivo de pesquisa do IBGE.

Olha como tá meu código até o momento:

```
 `f = open('exemplopesquisa.txt', 'r')
matrizex=f.readlines()
print(matrizex)
for line in matrizex: 
    #Separa a string por ;
    Type = line.split(";") 
    a = Type[0] 
    b = Type[1]
    c = Type[2]
    d = Type[3]
    e = Type[4]
    f = Type[5]
    g = Type[6]
    h = Type[7]
    i = Type[8]
    j = Type[9]
    k = Type[10]
    l = Type[11]
    m = Type[12]
    n = Type[13]
    o = Type[14]
    p = Type[15]
    q = Type[16]
    r = Type[17]
    s = Type[18]
    t = Type[19]
    v= Type[20]
    print(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,v) 
print(matrizex[0:801])
if
print(len(matrizex))
print(len(line))
if 'T001' in line[0:60]:
    print("TUDO OK")
for linha in matrizex:
    if 'T001' in linha:
        print("ok")`
```

Os arquivos estão nessa pasta: [Link com os arquivos txt](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_6ZBDbT9c_T-axHw-h0WomMQDeVG-Gvo?usp=sharing)

Comment: Tem como colocar de forma clara um exemplo de conteudo para cada um dos arquivos ?  De preferência com mais de uma linha

Answer (score 2):

Há várias questões a serem trabalhadas no código proposta, mas parabéns pela eloboração da pergunta. Mostrou esforço.

use o comando `with open` quando abrindo arquivos em Python ao passo que define melhor seu escopo, assim como já se encarrega de fechar o arquivo assim que o escopo é terminado.

Como você está trabalhando com um txt do IBGE provavelmente haverá caracteres em UTF-8. É sempre bom especificar isso quando abrindo arquivos de texto. Para tal, use `encoding`.

```
matrizex = list()
with open('arquivo.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip() # limpar possibilidade de espaços adicionais
        matrizex.append(line.split(";"))
```

Em `matrizex` você terá uma lista de listas, ou seja, uma lista de linhas do seu arquivo.

Você pode repetir esse processo para cada um dos arquivos e salvar em listas diferentes.

Identifique qual a posição das variáveis que você gostaria de identificar, pelo que entendi, o ID é sempre o primeiro valor no arquivo que você apresentou.

Digamos que você queira bater se esse ID existe em outro arquivo. Para tal, vamos assumir que você repetiu o processo acima e salvou o outro arquivo da mesma forma, mas na variável `matrizey`.

Logo, para identificar se o ID (que se encontra sempre no index 0 das linhas) existe também no outro arquivo (vamos assumir que ele também se encontra no index 0 das linhas), você faria o seguinte:

```
for line in metrizex:
    ID = line[0]
    for line2 in metrixey:
        if ID == line2[0]:
            print("ID:{} exists in both files!".format(ID)) # print the result
            # do something
```

Você pode repetir esse processo no outro arquivo também e com outros indexes para varificar as variáveis que precisar.

Uma sugestão também, para fazer analise de dados tabulares em Python é usar a biblioteca Pandas. Ela facilita bastante esse tipo de operação que você precisa.
Segue o link para você dar uma olhada:
https://pandas.pydata.org/

Espero ter ajudado!